# Is there a way to set and evaluate a value at the same time in python?

Tags: python

I'm new in python but I have used java and there's a *trick* that I use very often and **I'm wondering if this exists in python**

I'm currently coding a chess and I need to call a function to check if I can use a value, if it is the case, I will use it. It would look like this in java:

```
int x;
if( isValid(piece, x = piece[1][0]) ) moves.add(x);
```

As you can see, I'm setting a new value to x, and then I will just call it in case I need it, it's useful when I have many `if` sentences, or when the value I use is too long so it'd be hard to read.

**Does python have something similar?**

Comment: Assignment expressions (also known as the walrus operator) were added in Python3.8 https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions

Comment: Yes but only on python >=3.8: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent in python since 3.8 is likely

```
if isValid(piece, x:=piece[1][0]):
    moves.add(x)
```

The "walrus" operator `:=` binds the second positional argument to local variable `x` before making the call (the assignment is there even if `isValid` raises an exception). If "x" is a keyword argument, it looks a bit different

```
if isValid(piece, x=(x:=piece[1][0])):
    ...
```

so local `x` is bound and then keyword argument `x` is set before the call. And of course the names don't have to match

```
if isValid(piece, other_keyword_param=(x:=piece[1][0])):
    ...
```